# what causes java minor gc

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am talking about UseParNewGC. My understanding of the java gc minor collection goes like this. When, jvm detects that the eden is full (or it can't satify an allocation request)

1. It stops all app threads
2. Computes the live objects in eden and one survivor space, and moves them to another
3. If there is n't enough space for the move, or if the objects in survivor are old,enough, it does a promotion into old gen.
4. Marks eden and the cleaned survivor as empty
5. resumes app threads.

Is the exactly right?  Is there a case when minor gc will be triggered even though eden is not full?

Comment: Eden and the originating survivor space are emptied, they aren't just marked as empty, they are overwritten with nulls (or some other more appropriate value).

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the process right. There are situations where a major GC is triggered for reasons other than a full eden space, such as a call to `System.gc()`, or RMI. In that case a minor GC will also be run.

Comment: I am actually asking about minor gc only. PS: I have no system.gc calls or RMI.

Comment: In addition to the rules you list, some JVM implementations may decide to grow the young generation instead of or in addition to performing a minor collection. Also, the definition of Eden being "full" may depend on the situation or be tunable by virtual machine parameters. These rules are sometimes quite complex, for Sun/Oracle JVM you can find some details here if you sift through the long document: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 0):

> When, jvm detects that the eden is full (or it can't satify an allocation request)
>   In a way, yes. But it dynamically sizes the generation to meet certain goals of the collector. Mainly pause time and fraction of CPU time spent in the GC.

So indirectly these goals dictate how often minor collections happen. Major collections may also trigger a minor collection before they run to reduce references to old objects from short-lived young ones.